# PHP login script redirects even when wrong username and password are provided

Tags: php, sqlite, redirect, authentication

That's the code

```
<?php

//Start session
session_start();

//Then we retrieve the posted values for user and password.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//Users defined in a SQLite database
$db = new PDO("sqlite:/www/test.db");
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'");

if ($result > 0)
{
  //If user and pass match any of the defined users
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  // close the database connection
  unset($db);
  header("Location: index.php");
};

//If the session variable is not true, exit to exit page.
if(!$_SESSION['loggedin'])
{
  // close the database connection
  unset($db);
  header("Location: login.html");
  exit;
};

?>
```

Database schema:

> Username TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, Password TEXT

The only row countains Username='admin' and Password='admin'

Any ideas why the script redirects me everytime to index.php even when the username and password are not in the database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put an exit(); behind header() to stop further execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$db->query` will return a resource if no error was encountered. Not the results of the query. So since your query executes just fine you're getting a resource handle which will always be > 0. That's why it seems everyone is successfully logging in.

You need to get the results of your query and check to see if the value of COUNT(*) is greater then zero (or equal to 1).

Comment: I thought doing the check `$result > 0` is enough for that.
Already tested the query and know that it outputs 1 for correct values and 0 for these that not exist in the columns.